# How to test performance of Mobile application using Appium and Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, appium-android, jmeter-5.0, appium-ios

I want to test the iOS or Android Mobile Application's client side performance using Jmeter and Appium. What are the steps to integrate Jmeter with Appium, from where I can take more reference so that I can successfully integrate the Jmeter with Appium and test performance of iOS or Android Mobile Application's client side performance.

I tried to search a lot about this how to integrate Jmeter with Appium to test client side performance of Mobile Application but didn't get more on the same

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JMeter to test client-side performance, one Appium should be sufficient.

However if you use JMeter for normal performance testing and want it to launch your Appium test as well in a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) it should be possible.

1. Download [Appium java client library](https://github.com/appium/java-client) and all its dependencies and copy them to ["lib" directory](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jars
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your test plan and choose [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the language
4. Put your Appium Java code into JSR223 Sampler